# Objective-C weird unzip behaviour results in corrupt files

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, compression, zip

I'm getting a very obscure issue.
If I zip something on the mavericks (right click -> Compress), it can be unzipped on mac, windows and linux, it works fine and all files present.

When I unzip it using "ZipArchive" or "SSZipArchive" on an iOS device, the same file is always corrupt.

If I zip the file through terminal it can be unzipped fine on the the ios device.

The file in question is a small 50KB video. I have tried setting different flags to see if I can recreate the issue through terminal to find out what flag is causing the issue, and I can't find the cause.

I have zipped the file with max compression and min compression to see if that's the cause and I have also tested the zip file to see if it's corrupt or has any hidden characters.

To make it weirder these zips will usually hold around 50 video files each and I have around 23 zips. The unzip code has been working perfectly until 2 weeks ago. Over the last 2 weeks I have found 7 corrupt files, and corruption is consistent - it is always the same files that are always corrupt.

The corrupted file is usually a few kb smaller than the working one, it can't be opened or forced to play.

They where all originally zipped using mavericks, and nothing has changed.

The issue has now become more about fact-finding, as I can zip the files through terminal but I would like to know what causes the issue, so I can steer away from it in future.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure those ZIP files you try to extract on your device are actually are identical to those you can extract on the other platforms - maybe your delivery mechanics are broken.

Comment: Yep, extract a file using the "bad" mechanism and compare it to the same file extracted from the same zip with a "good" mechanism, to see what's different.

Comment: they are identical, we even tried adding them our self to the device, we still face the same issue. we initially thought as they are going over SSL thats causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The right-click -> Compress option on OSX creates a zip file containing an extra directory called `__MACOSX`, which contain metadata  [used by the Finder](http://old.floatingsun.net/2007/02/07/whats-with-__macosx-in-zip-files/) (image thumbnails and other  things). See also [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/104500/what-is-macosx-folder) for a more detailed explanation.
The reason this folder exists is because the original Mac OS implemented the concept of a resource fork - essentially a way of storing structured data about a particular file/directory alongside unstructured data, so it can easily be accessed by executables- Wikipedia article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork) (also referenced in the SU question)

iOS doesn't understand this structure so the unzip fails.

Comment: That would be a perfect explanation. Had not been working for 1.5 years and all of a suddenly decided not to work.  
The other information recently found is it doesn't like windows zipping either using the python library.  But never te less thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So after spending days investigating this issue, the issue turned out to be a flag in the video conversion script that was causing this issue, we also removed all compression on all the files to be safe, everything seems to be working. 
A big thanks to everyone who contributed.